# C++98 v. C++11 std::set::insert Specifications

Tags: c++, c++11

The meaning of the iterator passed as a position hint to `std::set::insert(iterator position, const value_type& val)` and `std::multiset::insert(iterator position, const value_type& val)` changes between C++98 and C++ 11. Is there an easy way at compile-time to detect which is in use and use different code?

A general check on C++11 does not appear to be a good idea ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717502/is-there-a-preprocessor-directive-for-detecting-c11x-support), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047971/how-do-i-check-for-c11-support)), and I didn't see a suitable [Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) macro.

Specifically, the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/insert/) for C++98 says:

> The function optimizes its insertion time if *position* points to the
> element that will **precede** the inserted element.

while for C++11 it says:

> The function optimizes its insertion time if *position* points to the
> element that will **follow** the inserted element (or to the end, if it
> would be the last).

This matters because the hint effects the complexity of the insertion call. If the hint is correct, the complexity is only an amortized constant. But if it's not, it's logarithmic in size.

#### Update

As so nicely described below by JerryCoffin, the C++98 specification is, essentially, a typo.

Comment: IIRC the standard was changed to match (most of) the existing implementations, so your test may not be such a good idea. At least you should check the compilers you are using.

Comment: I just verified this in the standard; I had no idea. Alas, no, there is no way to check but as Marc says you don't really need to. Assume the C++11 behaviour and you should be okay.

Comment: @Jerry: Bah, literally _just_ found that myself (well, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#233 anyway, and [n1780](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1780.html)). You may take the answer.

Comment: All. That is great to know (tho' now I have some other old code to fix :P ). Thanks. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was the subject of a [defect report](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_frm/thread/6ff4ab58318f0870/52c2484d42d2a083), [LWG issue #233](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#233), and [n1780](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1780.html).

As noted there, it was apparently a simple error in editing the C++98 standard.

Stepanov's original implementation worked according to the current specification, and as far as I know most (all?) implementations since have done the same (though there is one that looks both before *and* after the hinted location, so you'll get optimal behavior if you specify either one).

This also makes it possible to hint that an insertion will be at the beginning of the set, which wasn't possible under the previous specification.

Comment: which implementation looked at before and after?  That's interesting to me

Comment: @MooingDuck: I don't remember. It's mentioned in the DR, and at the time I managed to track down which one it was, but in the ~15 years since, I'm afraid I've forgotten which it was.