# What's a quick simple bit of code to verify a given C++ compiler is reading source as C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I think my compiler understands C++11, but maybe not.  Instead of trying it on existing messes of source code which are buggy anyway, is there some simple "hello world" level snippet of source code I can try to compile, which if it does compile without error, proves the compiler is reading it as C++11?

Comment: Try passing `-v -std=c++11` flags to your compiler.

Comment: Look at this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10717525/2502409

Comment: You can use the standard "hello world" program, just replace the string with a raw string literal - `R"(Hello World!)"`

Comment: @Praetorian R could be a macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one,

`auto f = [](){};`

or write some code with rvalue reference.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is correct, but from what I'm reading in 2019, it looks like that in the upcoming C++20, []<>(){} will be legal.

Answer (score 3):

Shortest thing possible:

```
[]{};
```

Is's a lambda-expression without argument list.

Answer (score 3):

The Problem is that compiler usually don't support a new standard completely from the start. Meaning, they may support one c++11 feature, but not another.

However, as far as c++11 is concerned, I think VC++ is the only major compiler that doesn't fully support it, even though you may have to enable the c++11 mode manually. For g++ you e.g. have to supply the compiler flag -std=c++11 (or -std=gnu++11) - the same holds true for newer versions like c++14).

Comment: Can someone mark it as duplicated of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047971/how-do-i-check-for-c11-support